# Softmax not giving probability of each class

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I'm just doing a simple DNN on the Fashion MNIST dataset and I have my last layer set to 10 units with softmax activation.  What I'm expecting is to see a probability of each class that it can possibly be but all I'm getting is 1 as if its a binary classifier.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong!

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

#Loading data and setting the training, validation and test samples
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(X_train_full, y_train_full),(X_test,y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:5000]/255. , X_train_full[5000:]/255.
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]


#Creating the model
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28,28]),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'),
])

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))

# Predicting values
X_new = X_test[:3]
y_proba = model.predict(X_new)
y_proba.round(2)
```

This is where I'm expecting to see a few classes with percentages (decimals) but I'm getting all 1s... I looked through all 1000 test samples but for simplicity I'm only displaying the first 3:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

What am I not getting? or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you inspect the whole predictions by doing `y_proba = model.predict(X_test)`? Because I got some decimals in the prediction array. You can also try predicting without fitting the model to data.

Comment: I tried that I'm not getting any decimals.  Like I said I chose to show only 3 records above only to show as an example.  I'm running this through Jupyter notebooks, not sure if its a setting there but the numpy array is clearly a float32 so I should have at least 2 decimal places!

Comment: Can you try filtering some values with `filtered_arr = y_proba[y_proba != y_proba.astype(int)]`. And see what's inside `filtered_arr `.

Comment: Interesting!  I got an array of shape (751,) and a lot of the values are in the 1e(-)double digits.  Any idea why I'm getting such "accurate" numbers? the model is quite simple so I would expect to see a lot more uncertainty.
As an aside, I just got upgraded to a new laptop and thats when I started seeing this strange behavior

Comment: The model could be simple but also dataset is very well prepared. That could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the prediction with `X_valid` as you have trained your model by subsetting the dataset into `(X_train, y_train)` and `(X_valid, y_valid)`:

```
# Predicting values
X_new = X_valid[:3]
y_proba = model.predict(X_new)
y_proba
```

Output:

```
array([[8.7486797e-15, 4.1651571e-14, 1.4356388e-15, 2.7562514e-19,
        6.6444322e-15, 2.3569682e-10, 8.2472345e-15, 3.0666047e-03,
        4.6038006e-14, 9.9693334e-01],
       [9.9992633e-01, 1.2232946e-16, 2.8763867e-05, 6.6998540e-10,
        3.3127880e-09, 4.4620761e-18, 4.4978275e-05, 7.2699694e-15,
        9.3659594e-12, 3.5588103e-24],
       [9.8151851e-01, 1.6080153e-04, 7.4726825e-07, 1.8097689e-02,
        1.4498403e-08, 1.7963254e-10, 2.2226702e-04, 2.8377571e-15,
        4.3501883e-13, 4.1252978e-12]], dtype=float32)
```

After rounding the prediction:

```
y_proba.round(2)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ],
       [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.98, 0.  , 0.  , 0.02, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Check the predcition for first 3 values of `X_valid`:

```
for y in y_proba:
  print(np.argmax(y))
```

Output:

```
9
0
0
```

if you want to compare these values with `y_valid`(actual label):

```
y_valid[:3]
```

Output:

```
array([9, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

You can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#make_predictions) link to know more about plotting predicted images with it's prediction percentage.